# Adaptive layout animation windows phone 10

Tags: animation, blend, windows-10-mobile

Hello I am working on windows UWP application. I want to make a swapping animation but when I run it on different screens the animation tends to fall out of place. I know the reason, its because the animations take margin movements from the initial position. I want to inquire that is there any way I can create an adaptive animation that considers screen size too?

Comment: have to tried doing it in blend ? When you set the screen sizes in the AdaptiveTriggers, the recording mode is on , there you can apply animations ?

Comment: I've made the animations in blend itself. but the animations are dependent to the designer device. so if I made the animation in blend as 4" screen size of designer then for other device sizes the animation goes out of bounds